# How to convert complex number on Y axis to normal number in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

In this image as we can see that numbers on y axis are too large to print so, it is shown as complex number but how can I print normal number on Y axis.

The code I am typing is

```
ggplot(vtUseful, aes(stars, usefulVote)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', fill = "cyan", col = "black", width = 0.50) + 
  labs(x = 'Star Category', y = "Sum of Useful Vote") + theme_minimal()
```

Comment: `options(scipen = 99)` and run the plot command again.

Comment: @RonakShah my problem with changing scipen is that 1) it often makes very large numbers difficult to read, and 2) it makes a persistent global change to number printing behaviour. I think telling ggplot how you want to format the numbers is probably better than changing global options, but I guess it might make things a little less confusing for beginners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not complex numbers, but scientific notation, where the `+e05` means `* 10^5`. To display it in a legibile numerical format, you can add

```r
+ scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)
```

For example, if I have the following plot:

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, 1e8 * Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

I can get rid of the scientific notation by doing

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, 1e8 * Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)
```

[image]

Comment: I have improvised my code just like you @Allan Cameron suggested ggplot(vtUseful, aes(stars, usefulVote)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', fill = "cyan", col = "black", width = 0.50) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma()) + 
  labs(x = 'Star Category', y = "Sum of Useful Vote") + theme_minimal()
Error is Error in number(x = x, accuracy = accuracy, scale = scale, prefix = prefix,  : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default

Comment: @V.Patel that is _not_ my code. You have put brackets `()` after `scales::comma` which is why you are getting the error. If you remove these it should work.